# Is it possible to create google script triggers programmatically with Golang?

Tags: go, google-apps-script, triggers, google-apps-script-api

I am trying to create a trigger for a google script using Golang. I am able to create the program and script, but I also need a trigger to run the script and enable it to do certain actions. It's easy enough to make a trigger through the dashboard or using an existing script file (.gs).

However, I would like to use Golang to manage the entire process. I have looked at the docs and the only examples they have for creating triggers is in the google script format and I cannot seem to find any support for other languages.

Is this API available and I am just looking in the wrong place or is this something that must be done in the dashboard or through a google script?

Comment: Take a look at [Class ScriptApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app).

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no APIs for directly installing the trigger yet. As a workaround, I had confirmed that the trigger can be installed from outside using Web Apps. The flow is as follows. 1. Create a Google Apps Script for installing triggers. 2. Deploy the script as Web Apps. 3. Run the Google Apps Script by the request of golang. At that time, you can also include the parameters for the trigger. I actually implement this flow using golang. If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Tanakie, thanks very much for the clarification. I think your suggestion is a good workaround for now. Obviously, it's not ideal, but it should yield my intended outcome.

Comment: @J.Langford If you are looking for the samples, please tell me. For example, you can see an application that I implemented this flow at [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/ggsrun/blob/master/help/README.md#createtriggers).

Comment: @Tanakie, wow thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @J.Langford I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 2):

After following @Tanakie's solution I ended up seeing a definitive answer to my question here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute?authuser=1. Number 4

[image]